# Why is "docker start" outputting the name of the container?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I have a small minimal test container made using the ruby image. The ruby script is simple, and outputs the single string "Twitter".

When I first run the image and create the container, I get this output:

```
$ docker run -it --name my-running-script my-ruby-app
Twitter
```

Great so far - the script completes and the container exits.

But when I try to start it again, it first outputs the name of the container:

```
$ docker start -a my-running-script
my-running-script
Twitter
```

What is causing this output, and how can I get it to stop? (It's printed on stdout, and redirecting stderr doesn't help.)

I don't know if it's relevant, but this is running on OS X using boot2docker.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior for docker start.   Then you can do things like assign the containerID to a variable, etc.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Can you point me at some examples of this?

Comment: There's no mention of this in the command line reference: https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#start

Comment: And how would you start the container if you didn't already have its ID (or name)?

Comment: Moreover, docker run doesn't output this, where it would seem to be more useful (though docker create does, which makes sense, since you're not actually running the container).

Comment: Interesting; `docker run -d` outputs the container id whereas `docker start` outputs the name (apparently). You may be able to use `docker attach` or `docker logs` to get around this issue I guess.

Comment: Run is before a container has a name.   Start is after a container has been run (with or without a name).

Comment: I guess the issue completely escapes me.    Redirect all your output to stdout and get it via docker logs or one of the various other approaches.

Comment: The point is that I'm capturing other output from the container, and having to filter out the name is pretty annoying.