# docker run image vs start container

Tags: docker

I am new to docker.

My first tried eaxmple is hello-world, CLI I used is "docker run hello-world". When I tried to remove the image, it says "one container is using its reference." So I found/delete the all containers that created by hello-world image.

When I execute "docker run hello-world", it will create a container and print texts. But when I do "docker start [container name/id]", it doesn't print the expected texts.

```
docker:~$ sudo docker container ls --all
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND    CREATED         STATUS                     PORTS     NAMES
4c792389afa8   hello-world   "/hello"   3 minutes ago   Exited (0) 3 minutes ago            gifted_khorana

docker:~$ sudo docker start 4c792389afa8
4c792389afa8
```

Should I do "docker run image" to create/start container every time? Or Just do "run images" once, and use "start container" to start it?

Comment: You shouldn't ever need `docker start`.  If you have a stopped container, you'll get more consistent results if you `docker rm` it and `docker run` a new one.

Comment: You might be looking for [How to start an existing docker container with displaying the output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437372/how-to-start-an-existing-docker-container-with-displaying-the-output) or [Why is "docker start" outputting the name of the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27987680/why-is-docker-start-outputting-the-name-of-the-container), which both suggest `docker start -i` in this situation.

Comment: @DavidMaze If I use "docker run image" everytime, it will create a new container every time. So I think we should re-use the container instead of creating a new one. "docker start -i xxx" will output the expected text.

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` to use docker. Consider adding the group `docker` to your main user. `sudo usermod -aG docker <user>`

Comment: A Docker container is just a wrapper around a process; there's no particular reason to try to preserve it.